# any better way than using old servlet api for downloads

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I am wondering if the following code can be modified to be used with latest version of spring APIs?
The following code works fine. However, I wanted to know if servlet APIs can be avoided which i have used in the code below.

```
public void download (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable String filename, @PathVariable String user) throws IOException{
              
            String param1 = filename;
            String param2 = user;

            //The following URL will need to be updated with "prod" or "dev" or "test" depending upon the environment
            final String FILE_LOCATION = "/mnt/nfs/myfolder/prod/documents/custom_documents/"+param2;
            
            
            if(param1 == null || param2 == null) {
                // The Request Parameters Were Not Present In The Query String. Do Something Or Exception Handling !!
                System.out.println("Request Parameter Not Found in first if!");
            } else if ("".equals(param1) || "".equals(param2)) {
                // The Request Parameters Were Present In The Query String But Has No Value. Do Something Or  Exception Handling !!
                System.out.println("Request Parameter Not Found in second if!");
            } else {

            
                String fileName = (String) param1;
                String contentType = getContentType(fileName.split("\\.")[1]);
                File file = new File(FILE_LOCATION + "/" +fileName);
                response.setContentType(contentType);
                response.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + fileName);
                response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
                ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                int bytesRead = bufferedInputStream.read();
                while (bytesRead != -1) {
                    servletOutputStream.write(bytesRead);
                    bytesRead = bufferedInputStream.read();
                }
                if (servletOutputStream != null) servletOutputStream.close();
                if(bufferedInputStream != null) bufferedInputStream.close();

            }
            
            
            
    }




private String getContentType(String fileType) {
        String returnType = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < contentTypes.length; i++) {
            if(fileType.equals(contentTypes[i][0])) returnType = contentTypes[i][1];
        }
        return returnType;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Resource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html) interface provides an effective way of accessing the content of the resource and supports handling of all kinds of file resources. Please see if that helps you to some extent.

```
public ResponseEntity < Resource > downloadFile(String fileName) {

  final String FILE_LOCATION = "/mnt/nfs/myfolder/prod/documents/custom_documents/";

  File file = new File(FILE_LOCATION + "/" + fileName);

  Path path = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
  ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(Files.readAllBytes(path));

  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  //headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + file.getName());

  return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).contentLength(file.length()).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).body(resource);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try to test it and see how it goes. Will update here after I'm done with the testing.

Comment: 1) Have you not taken `user` variable into account in your solution?2) It's asking me to change the method return type as shown in the screenshot below: https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Coc.png